# Android Eclispe : 2 .java files in editor, how to set1 file as startup

Tags: android, eclipse

In nutshell, i am trying to add multiple examples, by adding multiple .java files, in editor but all the time, mainactivity.java file is being executed. How could i make other file as start up file.

Answer (score 3):

If your other file is also an `Activity`, which it must, you will have to change your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Add a new entry for your new `Activity`, and add the Main and Launcher Intent filter:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Also make sure to either remove the `Intent Filter` from the Manifest entry of the old `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks a ton, i was looking into the project properties but did not find it.

Answer (score 0):

Yep you are gonna use the **AndroidManifest.xml** file, you can actually even have more than one launcher activity specified in your application manifest. To make an activity seen on the launcher you add these attributes to your activity in the manifest

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Change this**.Launcher** to Default for your **MainActivity**  and Add **.LAuncher** in that activity you want to Launch First